# Django was deleted parent relation when i delete child

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class One(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

class Two(models.Model):
    one_first = models.OneToOneField(One, related_name='first', null=True, blank=True)
    one_second = models.OneToOneField(One, related_name='second', null=True, blank=True)
```

When I do `two_instance.one_second.delete()`, Django deletes the one instance (which I want), but it also deletes the two instance. Why does it delete `two_instance`?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. `two_instace.one_second` is the related `One` instance, so `two_instance.one_second.delete()` deletes that one instance. What did you expect it to do instead? If you want to clear the value of the one-to-one field, set `two_instance.one_second = None` then call `two_instance.save()`

Comment: when Two_instance.one_second.delete() delete one_instance and delete two_instance to. I want delete one_instance only. I not understand why django delete two_instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Django < 2.0, [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) defaults to `CASCADE`. That means that when the `two` instance is deleted, the related `one` instance is deleted as well.

You can change this behaviour by using a different value for `on_delete`. For example, you could use `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`, which will set the value of the one-to-one field to `None` when the related object is deleted.

In your case, you have two one-to-one fields pointing to the same model, so you need to set `on_delete` for both fields.

```
class Two(models.Model):
    one_first = models.OneToOneField(One, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='first', null=True, blank=True)
    one_second = models.OneToOneField(One, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='second', null=True, blank=True)
```